# How to do *custom* action when receiving a warning in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, warnings, dtype

I have a script that iterates through thousands of csv's and reads them into pandas, then does a bunch of other stuff with it down the line.

Every once and a while, I get this message:

*sys:1: DtypeWarning: Columns (10,11,23) have mixed types.Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.*

I tried the try/except statement, however it isn't caught since its a warning and not an exception.

Is there a way to do something *like*:

```
try:
    df = pd.read_csv(file_path)
except pd.errors.DtypeWarning:
    df = pd.read_csv(file_path, low_memory=False)
```

I only want to use low_memory=False if i get the warning on that specific file, and not the the other thousands of files

I also can't just set all the column dtypes because many of the csv files have different columns/data/etc.

I don't want to set warnings.simplefilter('error', pd.errors.DtypeWarning) because it seems like overkill. I don't want some other DtypeWarning somewhere to keep it from running if I didn't catch it.

Answer (score 0):

`warnings.simplefilter` exists exactly for this purpose.
Inside the warning handler you can set conditions to make sure you don't catch unwanted warnings.

If the warning happens only "once in a while" than you probably want be wasting too much runtime on the warning handler code.